# What is "WebViewClient"?

Tags: android, webview

I was learning about webview in android when I came across this code: `webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());`

My question is what is WebViewClient and whether we can pass another activity context to this?

Answer (score 1):

`WebViewClient` is the object responsible for most the actions inside a WebView.

JavaScript enabled, security, routing, etc.

You can make a custom one, as well as use a Chrome one.

So no, you cannot pass an Activity as a WebViewClient, they are 2 different things. If you're looking to open an activity on some URL click, use `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` inside your custom WebViewClient.

Comment: can you show some code for `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`?